# Alter same COLUMN data type that exists in more than 3 tables in the same database

Tags: sql-server, sqldatatypes, alter

I have 15 tables, each table has a column `VAL` of datatype `varchar(100)`.

I was asked to change the datatype for all the `VAL` columns in all tables from `varchar(100)` to `varchar(200)`.

What is the best way to do it ? And how ? Procedure, Script, Loop, Statement..

Thank you all

Comment: 15 tables isn't many. Seems like you could just type this out yourself pretty quickly; you could have likely done this in the time you took to write this question and await my comment. `ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ALTER COLUMN YourColumn varchar(200);` took me all of 10 seconds to write (if that).

Comment: I know it's not many :) the whole concept is not to execute this way - what if they have asked me to alter for like 100 tables ?

Comment: Then you migh automate it but it also implies a possible design flaw if I am honest.

Answer (score 1):

You can run 15 alter table statements:

```
alter table table1 alter column val varchar(200);
alter table table2 alter column val varchar(200);
. . .
```

If typing 15 such statements is cumbersome, you can construct the queries using a spreadsheet or the `information_schema.tables` views.